# Buscar nomes em 2 tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quero pesquisar em 2 tabelas do banco de dados onde o nome seja igual a variável `$nome`.

Não gostaria de juntar dados como se fossem FK, mas puxar todas as informações dessas tabelas (outras colunas).

```
administradores
adm_id   | nome    | data_nasc  | cod_user |
1        | rafael  | 00/00/0000 | 63453    |
2        | paulo   | 05/06/2005 | 34241    |

usuarios
user_id  | nome     | sobrenome | cod_user |
1        | rogério  | silva     | 32412    |
2        | silvio   | lira      | 21321    |
```

Tentei fazer um `select` assim:

```
SELECT * FROM administradores.nome, usuarios.nome WHERE nome = '$nome';
```

Comment: E qual é o resultado esperado?

Comment: Buscar nas tabelas o nome

Comment: para trazer dados de duas tabelas você precisa faze um `join`. O que você espera receber com esse select? Trazer o nome das duas tabelas?

Comment: Poderia dar exemplos com base nos dados que você colocou nas tabelas? Se eu procurar por "paulo", qual seria o resultado? E se "paulo" estivesse nas duas tabelas?

Comment: `select * from tabela1 where campo = campo UNION select tabela2 where campo = campo`

Comment: @TeresaSantos, nesse caso, você pode usar um `join` ou o `union` como citado em algumas respostas .

Comment: Isso está me parecendo um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878) e só com os detalhes apresentados na pergunta não há como dizer se faz sentido ou não fazer o que está fazendo. Se são tabelas não relacionadas, não vejo porquê criar a relação na consulta.

Comment: Só quero criar um sistema de busca onde eu posso procurar em um só input nomes que estão em 2 tabelas separadas

Comment: Então melhore sua pergunta adicionando exemplos concretos. Coloque as estruturas completas das duas tabelas, alguns dados de exemplos e os resultados esperados para algumas consultas hipotéticas. Sem isso, não há como verificar a validade da solução e qualquer resposta será baseada em especulação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o "UNION" porém, precisaria ter os mesmos nomes de colunas para serem incluídas em ambos os "SELECT", porém, você poderá fazer um pequeno "ajuste" permitindo saber do resultado se é um usuário ou administrador:

```
SELECT user_id, 0 as adm_id, nome FROM usuarios where nome like '$nome'
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 as user_id, adm_id, nome FROM administradores where nome like '$nome';
```

Dessa forma os dois "SELECT" serão filtrados antes da união e seu resultado terá as colunas "user_id", "adm_id" e "nome".

```
user_id  | adm_id   | nome
1        | 0        | rogério
2        | 0        | silvio
0        | 1        | rafael
0        | 2        | paulo
```

Comment: Problema pode surgir quando ambas as tabelas possuem o mesmo nome. Dois resultados serão gerados. Piora se as colunas das tabelas não são iguais e piora se as duas pessoas não são a mesma pessoa. Se existir o administrador Fulano e o usuário Fulano, como saber quais dados utilizar?

Comment: Dessa forma que coloquei ele poderá distinguir usuário de administrador pelo id correspondente a cada tabela... como são tabelas diferentes tentei uma forma de usar as colunas da outra tabela atribuindo o id "0" (zero)

Comment: Digo no sentido de "buscar a data de nascimento do Paulo". Se existir "paulo" em ambas as tabelas e forem pessoas distintas, de quem eu pego a data de nascimento? Do administrador ou do usuário? E se uma das tabelas não possuir a coluna data de nascimento?

Comment: Bom aí vai depender de como o colega que fez a perguntar montar suas tabelas, isso será um caso a ele considerar.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu entendi da sua pergunta e levando em consideração a sintaxe que você já usou, para buscar tudo das 2 tabelas que possuam o mesmo valor da variável $nome, você pode fazer:

```
select * from administradores a, usuarios u where a.nome = '$nome' and u.nome = '$nome'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom Dia. 
Eu faria o seguinte:

```
SELECT adm_id, nome FROM administradores
WHERE nome = '$nome'
union
SELECT user_id,nome FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$nome'
```

Acredito que funcionará em qualquer banco de dados

Comment: E a questão das tabelas possuírem colunas com nomes diferentes? Se eu quiser verificar o id do resultado devo olhar o valor de `adm_id` ou `user_id`?

Comment: O Resultado sempre assumirá o nome dos campos do primeiro select. Obrigatóriamente, você precisa dar nome a eles se eles forem campos calculados, por exemplo:  SELECT VALOR_1 + VALOR_2 AS TOTAL....

Answer (score 0):

Você precisará usar o [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp):

```
SELECT adm_id AS id, nome 
FROM administradores
WHERE nome = 'nome_pesquisado'
UNION 
SELECT user_id AS id, nome
FROM usuarios
WHERE nome = 'nome_pesquisado'
```

Assim, serão retornados os nomes dos usuários/administradores pesquisados e seus *ids* (em cada tabela).